# google gs multiple calendars events to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

attempting to extract all day events from Google calenders (three in total), into three sheadsheet pages each with two set of three column data. Max is about 100 rows in a month takeout. the entries are searchable by name event as well.

help, runs sort of okay, but gives me a time out, which may be to much information, also error pops up with getTitle not found.

anyone with suggestions to improve code and prevent time out, or any other suggestions to tidy up code would be of help. My thanks in advance. 
This is what I have so far.

```
    function export_gcal_to_gsheet() {
// This selects events only from calendars in date and list out 
// Export Google Calendars Events to a Google Spreadsheet
// This code retrieves events between 2 dates for the specified calendar.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A6 listing the      events,and date
// I do re-write the spreadsheet header in Row 6 with every run, as I found it faster to      delete then entire sheet content,
// 1. Please modify the value for mycal to be YOUR calendar email address or one visible on your MY Calendars section of your Google Calendar
// 2. Please modify the values for events to be the date/time range you want and any search parameters to find or omit calendar entires
// Note: Events can be easily filtered out/deleted once exported from the calendar
// from an original file export_gcal_to_gsheet
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
var mycal="";
var mySite="canv";
switch (mySite) {
  case "canv"    : mycal = "*****orqjiaaosl0dt0qp0g@group.calendar.google.com"; break;
  case "salf"   : mycal = "*****juiigo83ich4iga7sttlpa4@group.calendar.google.com";  break;
  case "hart": mycal = "*****qblepqp88utr69vv434s@group.calendar.google.com"; break;
}//end switch

//var mycal = "*****hkdorqjiaaosl0dt0qp0g@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

// Optional variations on getEvents
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new       Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"));
// var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 3, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("January 14, 2014 23:59:59 CST"), {search: 'word1'});
// 
// Explanation of how the search section works (as it is NOT quite like most things   Google) as part of the getEvents function:
//    {search: 'word1'}              Search for events with word1
//    {search: '-word1'}             Search for events without word1
var eventsbell = cal.getEvents(new Date("May 1, 2014 00:00:00 GMT"), new Date("May 10, 2014 23:59:59 GMT"), {search: 'bell'});
var eventspers = cal.getEvents(new Date("May 1, 2014 00:00:00 GMT"), new Date("May 2, 2014 23:59:59 GMT"), {search: 'pers'});

//var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mySite);
// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before   running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost
sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A5:C5,E5:G5 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Delivery Branch test", "Customer and Site test", "Delivery Date test"]]
var rangebell = sheet.getRange(5,1,1,3);
rangebell.setValues(header);
var rangepers = sheet.getRange(5,5,1,3);
rangepers.setValues(header);

// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calculated ROW 6 (i+6)
for (var i=0;i<eventsbell.length;i++) {
var row=i+6;
for (var i=0;i<eventspers.length;i++) {
var row=i+6;
// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
var detailsbell = [[ mycal,eventsbell[i].getTitle(),eventsbell[i].getStartTime()]];
var rangebell = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,3);
rangebell.setValues(detailsbell);
var detailspers = [[ mycal,eventspers[i].getTitle(),eventspers[i].getStartTime()]];
var rangepers = sheet.getRange(row,5,1,3);
rangepers.setValues(detailspers);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote such a script some time ago and use it all the time without issues. Here is a simplified version of it that you could try to see if it eventually works for you.

The code is a bit long but the operation is all but simple so I guess there is probably no way to make it really shorter.

I know that some methods used in this code are being deprecated (getTimeZone for example) but it will be easy to update when they become unavailable... for now it works as it is, I'll update when I get some time to do it.

Here is [the link to a test sheet (in view only, make a copy to use)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1On2f_Qml8qXdS7zaJw-A879pFy80Y_Yl-kcm2eKmnbg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
var FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

function onOpen() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {name: "ImportCalendars", functionName: "Cal_to_sheetM"},  
  ];  
  ss.addMenu("import cals", menuEntries);  
}



function Cal_to_sheetM() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Import Calendars");
  app.setHeight(365).setWidth(600);
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(6, 2);
  var wait = app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3.gif').setVisible(false);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel("Cal Names :"));
  var list = app.createListBox(true).setVisibleItemCount(5);
  list.setName('calendar');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
  var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  for (var i = 0; i < calendars .length; i++) {
    list.addItem(calendars[i].getName());
  }
  list.setItemSelected(0, true);
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createCheckBox("add cal Name to events").setName('addName').setValue(false))
      .setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('start Date :'))
      .setWidget(2, 1, app.createDateBox().setId("start").setValue(new Date(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('startDate'))))
      .setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel('End Date :'))
      .setWidget(3, 1, app.createDateBox().setId("end").setValue(new Date(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('endDate'))))
      .setWidget(4,0, app.createCheckBox("create new sheet").setName('newsheet').setValue(false));
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(grid);
  var button = app.createButton('Import');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('importEventsMulti');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(wait).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setEnabled(false);
  button.addClickHandler(handler).addClickHandler(cHandler);
  grid.setWidget(5, 1,button).setWidget(4,1, wait);
  app.add(panel.add(grid));
  doc.show(app);
}


function importEventsMulti(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var calendar_name = e.parameter.calendar.split(',');
  var addName = e.parameter.addName=='true';
  var newsheet = e.parameter.newsheet=='true';
  var empty = ''
  var startDate = new Date(e.parameter.start);
  var endDate = new Date(e.parameter.end);
  var sheetName = calendar_name.join('&');
  if(newsheet){
      try{ 
    var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName,0);
      }catch(error){
        FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
        var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName+'-'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss"),0);
        }
  }else{
    var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var sheetNames = '';
    for(var s in allSheets){sheetNames+=allSheets[s].getName()};
    if(sheetNames.indexOf(sheetName)>-1){
        var newsheetName = sheetName+'-'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss")  
    }else{
        var newsheetName = sheetName
        }
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().setName(newsheetName); 
  }
  var eventArray = new Array();
    for(n=0;n<calendar_name.length;++n){
//Logger.log(calendar_name[n])      
      var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendar_name[n]);
      var events = Calendar[0].getEvents(startDate , endDate, {max: 4000});
      if (events[0]){
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var line = new Array();
          FUS1=events[i].getStartTime().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";
          var title = events[i].getTitle()
          if(addName){title+=(' ('+calendar_name[n]+')')}
          line.push(title);
          line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
          line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy")+' @ ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
          line.push(events[i].getLocation());
          line.push(' -- ')
          line.push(((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime())/ 3600000).toString().replace('.',','));
          line.push(' ')
          eventArray.push(line);
        }
      }else {
    var startstring = Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.start, FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy");
    var endstring = Utilities.formatDate(e.parameter.end, FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy");
    empty += calendar_name[n]+' - ';
  }
    }
  if(empty.length>1){ 
    Browser.msgBox('No events between ' + startstring + ' and ' + endstring +' in these calendars :'+empty);
  }
//Logger.log(eventArray)
    eventArray.sort(function(x,y){
      var xp = new Date(x[1].substr(6,4)+'/'+x[1].substr(3,2)+'/'+x[1].substr(0,2)+' '+x[1].substr(13,2)+':'+x[1].substr(16,2)+':00').getTime();
      var yp = new Date(y[1].substr(6,4)+'/'+y[1].substr(3,2)+'/'+y[1].substr(0,2)+' '+y[1].substr(13,2)+':'+y[1].substr(16,2)+':00').getTime();
      return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? 1 : -1;
      });
    // now check for any double entry starting from the end
    var eventArrayN = [];
    var doublons = [];
    for(i in eventArray){
      var row = eventArray[i];
      var duplicate = false;
      for(j in eventArrayN){
        if(row.join() == eventArrayN[j].join()){
          duplicate = true;
        }
      }
      if(!duplicate){
        eventArrayN.push(row);
      }else{
        doublons.push(row);
      }
    }  
    var titre = ['calendars '+calendar_name.join(' + '),'starting ','ending','Ressources','--','duration','totals'];
          eventArrayN.unshift(titre);
//Logger.log(eventArrayN.length);
//    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);   
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.getDataRange().clearContent().setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false).setBackgroundColor('#ffffff')
    sheet.getRange(1,1,eventArrayN.length,eventArrayN[0].length).setValues(eventArrayN);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 450).setColumnWidth(2, 150).setColumnWidth(3, 150).setColumnWidth(4, 250).setColumnWidth(5, 120).setColumnWidth(6, 75).setColumnWidth(7, 450);;
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1)
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,eventArrayN[0].length).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc').setFontWeight('bold').setHorizontalAlignment('center');
    sheet.getRange('G' + (eventArrayN.length+1)).setValue('Total (global)').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc');
    sheet.getRange('F' + (eventArrayN.length+1)).setFormula('=SUM(F2:F' + (eventArrayN.length)+ ')').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc');
    var max = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var cstart = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
    var n ;
  for(n=max;n>cstart;--n){sheet.deleteColumn(n)}
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  if(doublons.length>0){
    Browser.msgBox("There are duplicates in "+sheetName+", see log sheet");
    var sheet = ss.insertSheet('LOG-'+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), FUS1, "HH:mm:ss"),1);
    Utilities.sleep(1500);
    var titre = ['calendar : '+calendar_name.join(' + '),'start ','end','Ressources','--','Duration',' comments '];
    doublons.unshift(titre);
    sheet.getRange(1,1,doublons.length,doublons[0].length).setValues(doublons)
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 450).setColumnWidth(2, 150).setColumnWidth(3, 150).setColumnWidth(4, 250).setColumnWidth(5, 120).setColumnWidth(6, 75).setColumnWidth(7, 450);;
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1)
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,eventArrayN[0].length).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc').setFontWeight('bold').setHorizontalAlignment('center');
    sheet.getRange('G' + (eventArrayN.length+1)).setValue('Total global').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc');
    sheet.getRange('F' + (eventArrayN.length+1)).setFormula('=SUM(F2:F' + (eventArrayN.length)+ ')').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor('#cccccc');
    var max = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    var cstart = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
    var n ;
  for(n=max;n>cstart;--n){sheet.deleteColumn(n)}
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('startDate',startDate);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('endDate',endDate);
  return app;  
}
```

Comment: Serge, thank you, some great code,much better then where i was going. Reviewed the test sheet, a lovely example of widget box - works a treat. Forgot to mention in my original post that I need to search by event 'title word' to produce our spreadsheets,where would I add a search term and add a widget box.regards, Lee

Comment: let's be clear : you want to add a search field in the calendar selection panel and import only the events that contain that search item ?  Why not simply filter the spreadsheet, ie create a new sheet from a search in the first one. this would be quicker than importing calendar data don't you think ?

Comment: Wouldnt the timeout issue remain when there are too many events?

Comment: I use this code to read more than 600 events on  5 calendars without issue...bulk reading is pretty fast...I have a similar script that works backwards (sheet to Cal) and this one needs to break the task in multiple bunches... I should'nt worry too much but give it a try before going further :-)

Comment: Oooops, sorry Zig, I didn't notice you were commenting, thought it was the post author :-) .Anyway first part of my comment remains valid :-)

Comment: I was concerned with timeout,but can filter spreadsheet without any problem. This is used to issue to other departments quickly. We are likely to have 1000+ events per calender, which is why quicker to reduce down by search possibly to around 100 items per calender group into spreadsheet, which gets sent immediately as very time sensitive as well. Your code is very effective. regards, .

Comment: If you meet time out issues you can split the process quite easily... would you want me to show an example or shall we consider this as a "solved case"?  If yes then please consider accepting it , or let me know:-) -thx - note that I should have say "600 events on each of the 5 calendars..."important precision , that means 3000 events!

Comment: I'll come back if time out becomes a problem. I'am away from a live test place at present. Will try out properly with your code over next few days. Thank you Serge for help, was not expecting such a good result so quickly. Saved me hours of work. Solved case for me. Regards, Lee.

Comment: OK, let's go that way...I'll probably continue to think about the best splitting method. And don't forget to accept the answer. Bye

Comment: Hello Serge, been running script with perfect results for our needs.

Comment: Hello Serge, been running script with perfect results for our needs no timeouts at all.Only had minor problems, 1- timezone settings giving different date, 2-length of calendar name (ggogle restriction). Both easily resolved.thanks again. You mentioned in a previous comment "similar script that works backwards (sheet to Cal)" One of my directors like the script so much looking at other otions and the reverse script would likely work for us, any chance you could share that one as well/ regards, Lee

Comment: I can share it with you on gmail, but you'll have to adapt a few parameters yourself, just send me a msg , my email is sergegabet and is a gmail account of course  ;-). btw, please consider accepting the answer.